# Uploading image to jCrop

Tags: jquery, database, button, image-uploading, jcrop

I've been using the demo from http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail to create a cropper but it doesn't have a function to upload a picture to it. 
Do anyone know how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Upload Your Own Kiss</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>

<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var previewW, previewH, previewL, previewT;
var imagefile;

  jQuery(function(){
      jGo(true);
  });

  function jGo(changing) {
      setMainImage();
    // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
        var jcrop_api,
    boundx,
    boundy,

    // Grab some information about the preview pane
    $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
    $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
    $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),

    xsize = $pcnt.width(),
    ysize = $pcnt.height();

console.log('init',[xsize,ysize]);

if (changing) {
    $('#target').Jcrop({
      onChange: updatePreview,
      onSelect: updatePreview,
      aspectRatio: xsize / ysize
    },function(){
      // Use the API to get the real image size
      //this.setImage(imagefile);
      var bounds = this.getBounds();
      console.log("Bounds",bounds);
      boundx = bounds[0];
      boundy = bounds[1];
      //boundx = xsize;
      //boundy = ysize;
      // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
      jcrop_api = this;

      // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
      $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
    });
}
else {
    $pimg.css({
      width: previewW + 'px',
      height: previewH + 'px',
      marginLeft: '-' + previewL + 'px',
      marginTop: '-' + previewT + 'px',
    });     
}

function updatePreview(c)
{
  if (parseInt(c.w) > 0)
  {
    var rx = xsize / c.w;
    var ry = ysize / c.h;

    previewW = Math.round(rx * boundx);
    previewH = Math.round(ry * boundy);
    previewL = Math.round(rx * c.x);
    previewT = Math.round(ry * c.y);

    $pimg.css({
      width: previewW + 'px',
      height: previewH + 'px',
      marginLeft: '-' + previewL + 'px',
      marginTop: '-' + previewT + 'px',
    });
  }
};

  }

function showParams() {
alert ("Params are: " + ":" + previewW + ":" + previewH + ":" + previewL + ":" + previewT);
}

function sendParams() {
alert ("Params are: " + previewW + ":" + previewH + ":" + previewL + ":" + previewT);
 var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "save.php",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log((response=="ok")?"stored ok":"store error!");
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log("ajax failure!");
    },
    data: "imgURL=" + escape(imagefile) + "&x=" + previewW + "&y=" + previewH + "&l=" + previewL + "&t=" + previewT
});
}

function setMainImage() {
var imgFolder = "demo_files/";
imagefile = imgFolder + parseQuery(querystring)["image"];
//$('#target-pane').innerHTML('<img src="'+imagefile+'" id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]" />');
document.getElementById("target-pane").innerHTML='<img src="'+imagefile+'" id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]" />';
document.getElementById("preview-pane").innerHTML='<div id="preview-div" class="preview-container"><img src="'+imagefile+'" class="jcrop-preview" alt="Preview" /></div>';
}

var querystring = window.location.search.substring(1);  // looks strange, but it works

function parseQuery(str) {  // from StackOverflow - parses query string
if(typeof str != "string" || str.length == 0) return {};
var s = str.split("&");
var s_length = s.length;
var bit, query = {}, first, second;
for(var i = 0; i < s_length; i++)
    {
    bit = s[i].split("=");
    first = decodeURIComponent(bit[0]);
    if(first.length == 0) continue;
    second = decodeURIComponent(bit[1]);
    if(typeof query[first] == "undefined") query[first] = second;
    else if(query[first] instanceof Array) query[first].push(second);
    else query[first] = [query[first], second]; 
    }
console.log("parseQuery: query is ", query);
return query;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
<div class="jc-demo-box">

<div class="page-header">
<h1 style=color: whitel>Upload your own kiss</h1>
</div>
<div id="target-pane">
MAIN IMAGE
</div>

  <div id="preview-pane">
<div id="preview-div" class="preview-container">
  Preview img goes here
</div>
  </div>

  <div>
  <input type="button" value="Done!" onclick="sendParams();" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="text" id=paramsId />
  <input type="button" value="GetParams" onclick="getParams(getElementById('paramsId').value);" />
  </div>

  <div class="description">
  <p>
    <ul style=color:white;><b>Instructions</b>
    <li>Upload your image</li>
   <li> Crop it as close to your lips as possible (watch out for your nose!) </li>
   <li> Hit done when done!</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
  </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After it is cropped I would like it to be sent to another function so that people can flip the image before it gets saved in the database.

So far I have this:

```
<body onLoad="setUp();">

<div id="imbox">
<div id="left"><img id="leftimg" src="" /></div>
<div id="right"><img id="rightimg" src="" /></div>
<div id="checks">
    <span id=boxlspan><input type="checkbox" id="boxleft" onchange='flipIt("left")'> Flip?</span>
    <span id=boxrspan>Flip? <input type="checkbox" id="boxright"  onchange='flipIt("right")'></span>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

So to recap:
 1. Upload button that goes to Jcrop.
 2. Send picture button to flip.
 3. Send picture button to database.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's probably late to answer but hopefully will help others in future asking the same question. So, if you want to provide an image in your JCropper then you can either go with 2 of these options.

1) Let the user select an image and upload it to server and get the path and provide as source in JCrop target like this

```
    $('#cropbox').attr('src','http://www.mysite.com/upload/abc.jpg');
$('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    aspectRatio: 1, //To keep aspect ratio
    boxWidth: 650, //To handle large images
    boxHeight: 400, //To handle large images
        onSelect: updateCoords 
},function()
{
    alert("Image has been added to JCrop.");
});
```

2) If you want the user to select an image then crop and then upload then you can you use this code to do so but remember that this code uses **HTML5 File Reader API** which is not fully supported yet by all browsers but according to caniuse.com this feature is supported by 87% of todays browsers so I suggest to use this method.

```
<input type="file" id="uplPic" />

$(document).on('change', '#uplPic', function()
{
   if(window.FileReader)
   {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) 
      {
          $('#cropbox').attr('src',reader.result);
      $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
       aspectRatio: 1,
       boxWidth: 650,
       boxHeight: 400,
           onSelect: updateCoords 
      },function()
      {
       alert("Image has been added to JCrop.");
      });
       }
       reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);  
    }
 });
```

I have used JQuery for shorthand. Now you can get the dimensions and upload image to server and crop over there with PHP or other. Hope that helps.